# Why do these 2 NodeJS / Typescript imports give different results?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-modules, require

In a NodeJS project, I have installed `typescript` 3.2, `express` 4.16 and `@types/express` 4.16

I am writing my application in Typescript to be later transpiled. The documentation for `@types/express` say to import and use this way:

```js
import * as express from "express";
const app = express();
```

However when I do this, the 2nd line throws an error because `express` is not a function (does not have a call signature).  When I console log `express` I get an object with an `application` property

On the other hand, if I import and use this way:

```js
import express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Then everything works and console-logging `express` shows a function called `createApplication` or something similar.  The function itself seems to have the same `application` property from the 1st method.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [TypeScript@2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-from-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop) the following syntax for importing default module is supported:

```
import b from "bar";
```

Your example with * will import all of a module's exports [as a module object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax) 
but you probabaly want

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
```

Comment: Thanks Peter!  your first excerpt doesn't work; `express.application()` is not the same function as `express()` in your 2nd excerpt because the first one fails with "expected 2-3 arguments".  However you hit the nail on the head with the second excerpt: `import express from 'express'` is exactly what I wanted.  Please fix or remove the error code so I can accept your answer!